# How to add single item in PagingDataAdapter of paging3 library

Tags: android, android-paging-library

I have implemented paging3 library in chat application. I am showing messages in recycler view with paging, and it's working fine. Furthermore, I am also receiving message on socket which I have to add in adapter. Now I have to add single message object in adapter, but I have not found any function or way to add it in PagingDataAdapter adapter.

`class ChatAdapter() : PagingDataAdapter<UiModel, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffCallBack)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132278/how-to-update-single-item-using-paging-3-library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update single item using Paging 3 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132278/how-to-update-single-item-using-paging-3-library)