# How to insert item at a position using android Paging 3

Tags: android, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I am loading items from API using the Paging 3 library. I would like to add an item to a specific position in the recyclerview.

If I am using normal adapter I would just use

```
mArrayList.add(position, item);
notifyItemInserted(position);
```

But I am using the PagingDataAdapter and I have tried this

```
val newPostResponse = response?.responseBody
homeAdapter.snapshot().items.toMutableList().add(0, newPostResponse)
homeAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)
```

I have also tried

```
val newPostResponse = response?.responseBody
homeAdapter.snapshot().items.toMutableList().add(0, newPostResponse)
homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

None of these is working. Someone help me know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of [How to update single item using Paging 3 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132278/how-to-update-single-item-using-paging-3-library).

You must go through the `.invalidate()` loop to maintain a single source of truth and make Paging aware of your local changes. This is currently the only supported way to add an item to Paging.